# Check if file/page allows anonymous access

Tags: c#, global-asax

I'm working on the `Global.asax` file in the `Application_BeginRequest` method. How can I find out if the currently requested file requires authorization?

I know I can find out if the current user will have access to the file like this:

```
UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(path, user, httpVerb)
```

...but I need to know *if* the file is public or not regardless of the user making the request (whether they're logged in or not).

Passing in `null` for the user will throw an exception. Maybe I can pass in an instance of an *anonymous* user, but I don't know where to start with that.

I will be using this information to do further checks, as part of a validation for SSO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` method tells you if a certain user has access to a specific resource, passing in an anonymous user (rather than the current user) will tell you if *anyone* can access that resource.

1. Create the anonymous user:

   ```
   var anonymousUser = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(String.Empty, String.Empty), new string[] { });
   ```
2. Pass in the user into the `CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` method:

   ```
   bool isPublicResource = UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(virtualPath, anonymousUser , HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod);
   ```